# PFUser error on logout in Parse Objective C

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm getting the following error message when trying to call PFUser logoutInBackground:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x7af4bc00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7cd50eb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SDFDSDF-BC68-4SDF-sfdf-2GKJSKKSS/data/Containers/Data/Application/EA3BF90C-SDFJ-4153-AB1B-SDKFJNSDKJFN/Library/Private Documents/Parse/currentUser, NSUserStringVariant=(
Remove
)}
```

But if I print out the PFUser currentuser, it looks good!

```
<PFUser: 0x7cccb80, objectId: iFaGeM2vT, localId: (null)> {
didFinishCreatingAccount = NO;
"first_name" = F;
"full_Name" = "F F";
"last_name" = F;
peopleIFollow =     (
);
pictureFile = "<PFFile: 0x7c95b1d0>";
resetCode = 3274;
username = "+1245********";
}
```

The problem persists on the device as well...

Comment: Same problem here. Do you by now know the reason or do you have a workaround?